# jquery - unbind/bind button on ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm trying when I press a button to unbind it in the ajax response for 2 seconds and than bind it back on.

```
$('#invite').click(function(){
       /*ajax*/
 });
```

And ajax response:

```
//ajax response
function(rep){
/*do stuff*/
$('#invite').unbind();
$(this).delay(2000).bind();
}
```

But it doesn't works, the button remains unbinded forever, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't bind/unbind... it gets messy... :)

try putting a flag variable.

sample:

in here

```
var flag = false;
$('#invite').click(function(){
     if (flag) return false; // if flag is true, don't run codes below this line
     flag = true;
       /*ajax*/
});
```

then,

```
//ajax response
function(rep){
/*do stuff*/
setTimeout(function(){flag=false},2000);
}
```

well, something like that... or just change the `flag` variable accordingly if this sample did not work for you... you get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

*When you unbinding any thing from an element it doesn't store the info so when you binding it again there is nothing there to bind.*

If you want to bind it again just store the functionality in a function.

```
function x(){
 // any thing
  $('#invite').click(function(){
   /*ajax*/
  });
}
```

for binding

```
$('#invite').bind(x);
```

for unbinding

```
$('#invite').unbind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like This

```
function f1(){
             }

$('#invite').click(function(){
   f1();
});

$( "#invite" ).unbind( "click");
$(this).delay(2000).bind("click",f1);
```